# Выровнять ссылки по центру с фиксированной шириной

Tags: html, выравнивание

Ломаю голову над проблемой, есть блок скажем шириной 900px в него нужно поместить кнопки шириной скажем 200px разместить их по центру ну и придать красивостей. делаю с помощью такого кода

```html
<div class="buttons">
 <a href="#">link_1</a>
 <a href="#">link_2</a>
 <a href="#">link_3</a>
</div>
```

но ссылки расползаются по всему пространству дива. Если у кого нибудь есть варианты как решить подобную проблему подскажите плз

Answer (score 6, accepted):

добавляешь стиль,

```
.buttons {
  text-align: center;
}
```

и твои ссылки выравниваются по центру

Answer (score 2):

```css
.buttons{
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
 <a href="#">link_1</a>
 <a href="#">link_2</a>
 <a href="#">link_3</a>
</div>
```

[Как сделать подобное с помощью `Flex`.](http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/)

Answer (score 2):

`text-align: center` ?

```html
<style>
div {width: 100%;}
a {display: block; text-align: center;}
</style>
<div class="buttons">
 <a href="#">link_1</a>
 <a href="#">link_2</a>
 <a href="#">link_3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет такой вариант выравнивает их по центру и они выстраиваются в ряд, а мне нужно одна под другой тоесть вертикально.

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev, т. е. как вертикально? А в условие это не нужно написать?

Comment: @Constantine Shibaev, согласен, вы не написали это в задании. Вот так подойдет?

Comment: @Levelleor согласен затупил в условии не указал, даже при условии display: block; text-align: center; и если я ко всему этому ставлю фиксированную высоту как мне нужно они все равно расплываются в одну линию по горизонтали, вот что я имел в виду, прошу прощения за неадекватное изложение мысли (голова уже пухнет)

Comment: @Constantine Shibaev, расплываются по горизонтали? Этот код ставит их ровно в столбик по середине. Может вы у себя намудрили с стилями? Кстати если будете использовать подобный метод то выберите лучше вариант товарища "Other", я поленился сделать подобное.

Comment: @Levelleor о вместо text-align: center сделал margin: 0 auto; и получилось, все же нужно отдохнуть)) Спасибо вам.

Comment: @Constantine Shibaev, нет за что :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul{
 display:table;
 margin:auto;
}
ul li{
 display:table-cell;
 width:20%;
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<ul> 
 <li><a href="">Ссылка №1</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Ссылка №2</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Ссылка №3</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Ссылка №4</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Ссылка №5</a></li>
<ul>
```

самый простой способ

Comment: но правда width лишнее , применять надо padding и то не жеательно